# How to automatically scroll up or down the page to show the highlighted row all the time

Tags: javascript

I did a feature which could move the highlighted row up and down by keyboard. However, if I scroll down too far the highlighted table row will be disappeared. How to automatically scroll up or down the page to show the highlighted row all the time.
[image: inline]

Comment: Off the top of my head I think this requires the use of `event.scrollTop` and `element.clientY` javascript methods. Let me think about this while I drive home and if later nobody else posts an answer I'll come to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use highlighted class on row  and

add event listener on page scroll

if document scroll top value > .highlighted scroll top value

run function for scrolling to element